# xpath string to select a specific node with specific attribute

Tags: xpath

I have the follwoing HTML:

```
<div class=""postrow first"">
                <h2 class=""title icon"">
                    This is the title
                </h2>
                <div class=""content"">
                    <div id=""post_message_1668079"">
                        <blockquote class=""postcontent restore "">
                        <div>Category</div>
                            line 1<br /> line2
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=""postrow"">
                <h2 class=""title icon"">
                    second title
                </h2>
                <div class=""content"">
                    <div id=""post_message_1668079"">
                        <blockquote class=""postcontent restore "">
                        <div>Category</div>
                            line 1<br /> line2
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

What is the **xpath** string to select all DIVs with attribute is "postrow" or "postrow "

Comment: That's not valid HTML.

Comment: Does `//div[@class='postrow'] | //div[@class='postrow ']` work?

Comment: Did you mean to type all of those double-double-quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes that for each `""`, you actually have `"` in your document.

There are a number of alternative XPaths available to you. Here are just two:

- Using a conditional `|`:

  `//div[@class = "postrow"] | //div[@class = "postrow "]`
- Using `starts-with`:

  `//div[starts-with(@class, "postrow")]`